# can't get or set css of div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have the following html object

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="DataTables_Table_2_filter"><label>Sök: <input type="text" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_2"></label></div>
```

Now I want to manipulate this css interactively to position it the way I want.

When I try

```
$('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').css({"float":"left"})
```

nothing happens, and when I just try to alert out the current css of it

```
alert( $('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').css('float') );
```

I just get "undefined" in my alert box.

If I do

```
alert( $('#DataTables_Table_2_filter')
```

I get "Object objeect" in my alert box.

What is up with this?

Comment: Alert the length `alert( $('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').length)`

Comment: try `alert($('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').length)`

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JmLWg/

Comment: Let me guess. You execute your script directly and don't wait for page ready. Can that be?

Answer (score 1):

You might be accessing the elements before the are ready, use [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), because your code id working

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/dsrnP/)**

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="DataTables_Table_2_filter"><label>Sök: <input type="text" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_2"></label></div>

$(document.ready(function(){
   $('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').css({"float":"left"});
   alert( $('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').css('float') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').on('click', function(){
  alert( $('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').css('float') );
});
```

An see this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qKdQW/)

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

May be u have some conflicting ID problem outside of this code block because its working fine [In This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yjPYv/)

Html:

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="DataTables_Table_2_filter">
      <label>Sök: <input type="text" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_2"/></label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').css({"float":"left"});
alert( $('#DataTables_Table_2_filter').css('float') );
```